# I forgot what my Apple ID was, but I remember my password. How can I find my e-mail?

Tags: email, apple-id

So I remembered an older account that I had with apple and I remember the password. I remember there being a lot of games I liked and would like those back without having to pay again.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Apple made a site just to help you and others:

- https://iforgot.apple.com

Then click the link that says **Forgot Apple ID?**